# Navigation bar not working in mobile view

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a site and my main navigation is bar is not functioning in mobile view. When i click on the options in mobile view, the navigation section is getting closed but not redirecting to the respective page. My site link is : [click here](http://clouddatasol.com/home.html)

I hope someone helps me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From having a look through your code, it seems that you have some JavaScript library running `e.preventDefault()` on your `<a>` link elements.

The best solution would be to fix this problem, but a quick solution would be to use JavaScript inline to make the redirect, for example `<a href="erp.html" onclick="window.location.href = this.href">`.

Hope this helps.